# Passing dictionary as argument with different key name

Tags: python, dictionary

Im relative new to python and i still have problems thinking the pythonic way.
I have a funcion that has `CustomerAdd(id_type, id, name, email, adress, phone_number)` and want to pass the customer as argument: `CustomerAdd(**customer)`.

The problem that i have is that the expected customer format is:

```
{
  "name": [
    "CustName"
  ],
  "address": [
    "CustAddress"
  ],
  "id_type": "passport",
  "id": "123123123",
  "email": "test@email.com",
  "phone_number": "123123"
}
```

And my customer input looks like this:

```
{
  "id_type": "passport",
  "id": "123123123",
  "customer_name": "Gordon Gekko",
  "customer_address": "Fake Street 123",
  "phone_number": "123456789",
  "email": "customer@aol.com"
}
```

So, as you can see, i need to change the key names of customer_name and customer_address and also change the type of the values to a list.

I was able to change the key names with:

```
customer = old_customer.copy()
customer['name'] = customer.pop('customer_name')
customer['address'] = customer.pop('customer_address')
```

But still cant change the value type. Any ideas? Or any other pythonic way to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they need to be lists, just make them lists:

```
customer['name'] = [customer.pop('customer_name')]
customer['address'] = [customer.pop('customer_address')]
```